# Converting Set(float) into float/int

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have this df and trying to clean it. How to convert irs_pop,latitude,longitude and fips in real floats and ints?
[image]

The code below returns `float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'set'`

```
mask['latitude'] = mask['latitude'].astype('float64')
mask['longitude'] = mask['irs_pop'].astype('float64')
mask['irs_pop'] = mask['irs_pop'].astype('int64')
mask['fips'] = mask['fips'].astype('int64')
```

Code below returns `sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found`

```
mask['fips'] = mask['fips'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x))
```

`mask = mask.astype({'fips' : 'int64'})` returns `int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'set'`

Comment: there is no obvious way to convert a set to a `float`, so you are going to have to specify the behavior you need exactly

Comment: Can't you `map` your data with `float`?

Comment: i want them to be properly stored in the db for the future projects

Comment: well, your original attempt to store them as a string is reasonable enough, but instead of `','.join(x)` you need `','.join(map(str, x))`

Answer (score 0):

You would need to convert to tuple/list and to slice with `str`:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].agg(tuple).str[0]
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [{1},{2,3},{}]})
df['col2'] = df['col'].agg(tuple).str[0]
```

Output:

```
      col  col2
0     {1}   1.0
1  {2, 3}   2.0 # this doesn't seem to be the case in your data
2      {}   NaN
```

If you want a string as output, with all values if multiple:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].astype(str).str[1:-1]
```

Output (as new column for clarity):

```
      col  col2
0     {1}     1
1  {2, 3}  2, 3
2      {}
```

Comment: why would the OP just take the first item?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga no, `str` never raises errors if you try to slice empty iterables. It just assigns `NaN` (see my example). Regarding the potential multiple values, this doesn't seem to be the case, otherwise OP should clarify.

Answer (score 0):

So, you could do the following. Notice, you need to convert every element in the set to a `str`, so just use `map` and `str`:

```
mask['fips'] = mask['fips'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(map(str, x)))
```

This will store your floats as a comma delimited string. This would have to be parsed back into whatever format you want when reading it back.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for col in ['irs_pop', 'latitude', 'longitude']:
    mask[col] = mask[col].astype(str).str[1:-1].astype(int)
```

It looks like you have multiple FIPS in your FIPS column so you wont be able to convert to a single FIPS code. Most importantly, FIPS can have leading zeros so should be converted to strings.

Comment: "FIPS can have leading zeros so should be converted to strings." well, they are already floats, so that information is lost

Comment: floats can be made into strings with leading zeros

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have sets with a single value in these columns. The problem may be upstream where these values were filled in the first place. But you could clean it up by applying a function that pops a value from the set and converts it to a float.

```
import pandas as pd

mask = pd.DataFrame({"latitude":[{40.81}, {40.81}], 
    "longitude":[{-73.04}, {-73.04}]})
print(mask)
columns = ["latitude", "longitude"]
for col in columns:
    mask[col] = mask[col].apply(lambda s: float(s.pop()))
print(mask)
```

You could have pandas handle the for loop by doing a double apply

```
mask[columns] = mask[columns].apply(
        lambda series: series.apply(lambda s: float(s.pop())))
print(mask)
```